# Login Form for Admin and User

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need help about this, I've been working for this a quiet while...
I want to log-in using one login form for both admin and normal user but after log in, some of its form and/or buttons in the form should not be available for normal users.
here is my code upon login:

```
        If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all fields.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            cn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; User Id=root; Password=''; Database=omt"
            Try
                Dim sql As String = "SELECT Username, Password, Position FROM tbl_account WHERE Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
                cmd.Connection = cn
                cn.Open()

                Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If dr.Read = True Then
                    sql = ("SELECT Position FROM tbl_account WHERE Position = 'Admin'")
                    Me.Hide()

                    MDIParent1.Show()
                ElseIf sql = ("SELECT Position FROM tbl_account WHERE Position = 'User'") Then
                    Me.Hide()


                   MDIParent1.Show()

                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to databse. System Error:" & ex.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        If cn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End If
    End If
```

Comment: How do those last two queries make any sense? If you get the `Position` value where the `Position` value is "Admin" then obviously you're just getting "Admin". Likewise for "User". You're already getting the `Position` of the user who just logged in with the first query and that is what you care about. You need to set the status of your controls based on that value. Honestly, this is what happens when you write code without knowing what it has to do. Think about the actual steps the code needs to perform first, then write code to perform those steps.

Comment: Please use parameters like 'cmd.parameters.addwithvalue' instead of '+"'textbox1.text'" +'  because of Sql Injection.

Comment: @MertAkkanat Although using SQL parameters is correct, please take note of [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html) and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Scofield Apart from the issues pointed out by others, [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right) contains information which you should know about.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should seriously consider revising your authentication mechanism. Storing passwords in database tables (let alone as cleartext) is not a good practice.

Having said that, you can get the position of a successfully authenticated user (assuming it is stored in a not-null, character data type column, such as varchar(n)) like so:

```
Dim position As String = Nothing
If dr.Read = True Then
  position = dr("Position")
  Select Case position
    Case "Admin"
      ' TODO: Handle admin
    Case "User"
       ' TODO: Handle user
    Case Else              
        ' TODO: Neither Admin nor User. Now what?
   End Select
 Else
   MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.", 
        "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
 End If
```

You can then handle each case as you wish (show / hide the correct form, enable or disable form controls, etc).
Please excuse any syntactical errors, as I do not currently have access to Visual Studio.

Comment: Syntax looks good except you need an End Select. If you don't store passwords in a database (salted and hashed) where would you store them?

Comment: @Mary: Thank you for pointing out my syntax error. Regarding authentication, one could use integrated security if possible (so passwords are maintained in AD) or let sql server do the authentication (so passwords are maintained by the database engine). However, using salted and hashed passwords is also an option, so maybe I made an overstatement. But selecting username, password from a table as they were entered in a login form is really poor design, security-wise.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used. The you can assure that the are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for you even if there is an error.

I filled a `DataTable` instead of using the reader directly. I can use the data in the `DataTable` after the connection is closed. The connection must stay open while the reader is active. Closing the connection as soon as possible is very important. After the connection is closed you can check data an show message boxes.

ALWAYS use parameters to avoid Sql injection. Text passed as part of the command text is considered executable code by the server. Values passed to parameters are not executable.

Of course, NEVER store passwords as plain text. I will leave it to you to look into salting and hashing.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all fields.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return
    End If
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; User Id=root; Password=''; Database=omt"),
                cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Username, Password, Position FROM tbl_account WHERE Username= @User AND Password= @Password;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = txtUsername.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = txtPassword.Text
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using 'Closes and disposes the connection and the command
        If dt.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            If dt(0)(2).ToString = "Admin" Then
                'Do what you need for Admin
            ElseIf dt(0)(2).ToString = "User" Then
                'Do what you need for User
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Position doesn't match existing values.")
                Return
            End If
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
        Me.Hide()
        MDIParent1.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to databse. System Error:" & ex.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```